# ¿Cuál es la cualidad de una frase hecha?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En la expresión *[frase hecha](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IPhICME#67Mjybw)* el participio del verbo *hacer* tiene un significado bastante específico; un hablante que desconozca la expresión dudaría de su significado, tanto que *frase hecha* casi podría considerarse un [modismo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PUlqsDD). ¿Hay algún sustantivo abstracto, o al menos alguna frase nominal simple, que exprese con claridad **la cualidad de *ser hecha una frase***? (Mi pregunta va a que hoy me he visto obligado a acuñar la palabra *frasehechitud* para este propósito.)

(Puntos extra por sugerir un nombre abstracto también para **la cualidad de *ser un modismo***.)

Comment: En ELU he visto *idiomaticity*, que concuerda con la propuesta de @Gustavson, *idiomaticidad*....  Y tal vez *lo idiomático*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi propuesta:  [*unidad fraseológica* o *idiomaticidad*](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidad_fraseol%C3%B3gica).

Por un lado, "unidad fraseológica" es, según la página de Internet arriba vinculada, un término bastante abarcativo para designar al fenómeno por el cual se combinan palabras para conformar una frase hecha o un modismo. Otras denominaciones son: *expresión pluriverbal, unidad pluriverbal lexicalizada y habitualizada, unidad léxica pluriverbal, expresión fija o fraseologismo.*

> Se considera unidad fraseológica la combinación de palabras caracterizada por presentar un cierto grado de fijación o idiomaticidad, esto es, se trata de **combinaciones de palabras cuyo significado no se deduce necesariamente del significado de los componentes por separado** y tienen limitada "la modificación, la sustitución, la adición de complementos o cualquier otra alteración de su estructura", según Ruiz Gurillo.

La unidad fraseológica encierra dos aspectos: uno sintáctico (el orden de las palabras combinadas) y otro semántico, llamados respectivamente, según la página citada, "fijación" e "idiomaticidad". La fijación hace que la frase hecha no pueda alterarse (a menos que exista un juego de palabras deliberado), y la idiomaticidad permite que los hablantes reconozcan la unicidad del significado, más allá de lo caprichoso de la combinación. Abajo transcribo lo que dice la página al respecto:

> La unidad fraseológica debería cumplir, al menos, dos condiciones esenciales: fijación e idiomaticidad.
>
> [L]a fijación debe ser entendida como algo que el hablante almacena y tiende a reproducir sin descomponer la unidad en elementos constituyentes.
>
> [La idiomaticidad] se puede interpretar como el rasgo semántico característico de ciertas construcciones fijas.

Comment: Gustavson, he hecho unos edits, trayendo aquí un poco del contenido del enlace. Sería bueno que hicieses otro edit resaltando en negrita las partes que tú considerabas que eran las más importantes y añadiendo algo más de la página enlazada si crees que es oportuno. No pongas respuestas que son solo enlace sin explicar. Es mejor traer el contenido relevante al post.